# [SIP]How to verify that the other peer has answered the call

Tags: android, sip

I'm developping a SIP application and want to do some treatment when the other peer has answered an outgoing call.

```
A is calling B. If B answered the call make some treatment in A
```

I verified the documentation and i'm not finding a solution:
[Link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.html)
[Link 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.Listener.html)

Any idea please of how solve this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

part of sample code SipDemo

A call B

```
call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), "b-username@domain", listener, 30);
```

When B answer

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {  
        Log.v("call","b answering");                
        call.startAudio();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i've found it, but i have a question

```
public int getState ()

Since: API Level 9
Gets the session state. The value returned must be one of the states in SipSession.State.
Returns

the session state
```

How to put the constant `INCOMING_CALL_ANSWERING`in the gesState() ?

```
if (call.getState(INCOMING_CALL_ANSWERING))
```

??
It's not working.

EDIT: okay , i ahve to do like this:

```
if (call.getState()== 4)
```